Fubini for Hausdorff measures
Let $f \in L^2(S^{n-1})$, where $S^{n-1}$ denotes the $n$ dimensional sphere. Now, by using Fubini we can write
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1}} 1_{x \cdot y = 0} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(x) d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y) = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1}} 1_{x \cdot y = 0} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y) d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(x) = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1}} 0 d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y) d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(x) = 0,$$
since we have $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}({x\cdot y = 0}) = 0.$ This should be correct, but it doesn't feel right. I would be grateful for any feedback, thanks.
My aim is to prove that
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1}} 1_{x \cdot y = 0} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(x) d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y) = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1}} 1_{x \cdot y = 0} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(y) d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x),$$ how do I go about this?

You need both measures to be $\sigma$-finite to apply Fubini's/Tonelli's theorem. We know $\mathcal{H}^{n - 1}$ on $S^{n - 1}$ is finite, but $\mathcal{H}^{n - 2}$ on $S^{n - 1}$ is not; for example, for $n = 2$ the counting measure on $S^1$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

@Kakashi Thanks, do you know how to prove the equality in the last line?

I don't know why we would expect the last line to hold.

@Kakashi using a different notation with $y^\perp = { x : x \cdot y = 0}$, the last line is equivalent to $\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1} \cap y^\perp} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(x)d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y) = \int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{S^{n-1} \cap x^\perp} |f(x)|^2 d\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(y)d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x)$. This holds for continuous $f$, so I'm hoping it should work for $f \in L^2(S^{n-1})$, since this is technically Fubini in some sense?

I doesn't look like Fubini to me. On one side you have $|f(x)|^2dH^{n - 2}(x)$, while on the other side you have $|f(x)|^2dH^{n - 1}(x)$. It's not obvious to me why/whether it holds for continuous $f$.

@Kakashi I would rewrite the integral using dirac delta and use Fubini there, so the integral is the same as $\lim_{j \to \infty} \int_{S^{n-1} \times S^{n-1}} |f(x)|^2 \varphi_j(x \cdot y) d(x,y)$ and we can use Fubini to switch $d(x,y)$ to $d(y,x)$. ($(\varphi_j)$ is a Dirac sequence) and $d(x,y)$ denotes $d(\mathcal{H}^{n-1} \times \mathcal{H}^{n-1})(x,y)$

@Kakashi it works now, the integral is the same as $\int_{S^{n-1} \times S^{n-1}} |f(x)|^2 \delta(x \cdot y) d(x, y)$, where $\delta(x \cdot y) d(x,y)$ represents a Dirac delta integration. Then by using the orthogonal transformation that switches $x$ and $y$ and the orthogonal transformation, we get the equality with $\int_{S^{n-1} \times S^{n-1}} |f(y)|^2 \delta(y \cdot x) d(x, y)$.
